# views3 and SELECT

Tags: views

I use D7 and [Views3](https://drupal.org/project/views).

When I make a view with images don't appear in sql statements the reference after SELECT at the images.

I'd like to see a complete SQL statement for my development.

I don't believe it is a configuration problem.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase? I fail to understand what exactly does not appear in the SQL Query Views give to you, and why you expect to see that something.

Answer (score 0):

As you say this, **I'd like to see a complete SQL statement for my development.**

**Step 1:** Navigate to  `http://example/admin/structure/views/settings` and select the option **Show the SQL query** as in picture.

[image: views settings]

**Step 2:** Now try adding new or editing your views, below the views edit section there you can see all your SQL statements.